# How to change the innerHTML value specifically from the select tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on peice of code to allow user to create an customization on there domain. as you can see in the below example user can select **example.com** and change it to any **example(n).com** domain by selecting from below select tag.

What I trying to achieve is when I will select **example1.com** or **example3.com** the **http://** will change into **https://**

**example:**

when I will select example1.com from select list, the output will be

> **https://** example1.com
>
> **https://** example3.com

but if I select **example2.com / example4.com** it will remain as it is.

> **http://** example2.com
>
> **http://** example4.com

I am trying to achieve it in jquery. Any help and suggestion would be appreciated.

```js
function changeText(url)
  {
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = url;
  }
```

```html
<div>http://<span id='mydiv'>example0.com</span></div>

<select onchange='changeText(this.value)'>
  <option>example1.com</option>
  <option>example2.com</option>
  <option>example3.com</option>
  <option>example4.com</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this snippet.

```js
function changeText(urlPostFixNumber) {
    var protocol;
    var url;
    var domain = '://example' + urlPostFixNumber + '.com';

    switch(urlPostFixNumber) {
        case "1":
        case "3":
            protocol = 'https';
            break;
        default:
            protocol = 'http';
    }

    url = protocol + domain;
    document.getElementById('mydiv').textContent = url;
}
```

```html
<p id="mydiv">http://example0.com</p>

<select onchange="changeText(this.value)">
  <option value="0" selected>example0.com</option>
  <option value="1">example1.com</option>
  <option value="2">example2.com</option>
  <option value="3">example3.com</option>
  <option value="4">example4.com</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Also try to avoid using inline JS. Move out all logic into separate JS file. And stop using jquery :)

Comment: No need to parse a number, so I simplified the code some

Comment: thank you @LGSon for edit, agree. About code style it more clear to have a separate var declaration also it is diff-friendly for pull requests. Also naming should be clear and self explanatory.